# What happens with Google Drive files when a service account is deleted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have a GCP project which holds a service account. This service account has being used to create/share files in Google Drive through Google Drive API. This Service Account is not under any G Suite organization.

What happens with those files if the service account is deleted?

In case the files withstand the service account deletion, which account will have access to manage those files?

Is there a way to mass transfer the ownership of those files to another "usual" Google Drive account?

Answer (score 1):

When a service account is deleted, all the files in Google Drive belonging to that account are deleted as well.

Yes it makes sense to transfer the ownership of the files to another user. From the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing#transfer_file_ownership):

### **Transfer file ownership**

> To transfer ownership of a file in "My Drive," create or update a permission with the owner role and set the transferOwnership query parameter to true. When a file is transferred, the previous owner's role is downgraded to writer.

> Files existing in a shared drive are owned by the organization that owns the shared drive. Therefore, ownership transfers are not supported for files and folders in shared drives. Organizers of a shared drive can move items from that shared drive and into their own "My Drive" which transfers the ownership to them.